# openerp when in view mode fields lose context

Tags: view, odoo

From a form "A" I want to open a specific form "B" when I click on a Many2One field.
I placed into the context of this field the usual

```
'form_view_ref': 'model.form_id'
```

but this works only when "A" is in edit mode. If it is in view mode it opens instead the "C" form. I noticed that JSON request just "lose" the context i set and send the standard empty one (with just timezone/uid etc.)

I never realized this before. Is it some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alessandro Ruffolo,

context is variable between server client, and context has common attributes like uid, active_d, active_ids, active_model, User timezone, user lang. When calling an ORM method, you will probably already have a context - for example the framework will provide you with one as a parameter of almost every method.

If you do have a context, it is very important that you always pass it through to every single method you call. But when you don't pass context somewhere on any method in python or js client side server will generate new context, and their are so many place with old in core code that context is broken by not passing.
When you don't pass context, it breaks context and prepare new context.

With New v8 API context is more consistent as that’s not required.

Bests

Comment: So, you're telling me in some place in the old code there is a missing context-passing so a new one is generated? Because I am using API 8 in my code and for sure I am not missing any...

Comment: Yeah yoy understood it right, but when your client generate new request with with new view open with some action we clients will prepare new context based of your new action trigger,  so I will recommend you to pass your context from action or view to keep persistent on server calls