# Context not updated in onchange method (odoo-v8)

Tags: python, odoo

I have seen everywhere that odoo added **cr, uid, ids, context**.
**cr**, **uid**, and **ids** can be understandable, but **context** is for what ? why it's so important ?

By observing context I found that it's simple dictionary that mostly contains timezone and few more info only, so it's limited to only those values or something more which is important too ?

How could we use it better in programming ?
What are the advantages of context and what are the drawbacks ?

**Problem**

I want to exchange information between two onchange methods which are interdependent, like field discount and price - (new api odoo8).

While discount updated price will be changed and while price updated discount will be updated.

here is my code

```
@api.onchange('discount')
def discount_change(self):
    ctx = self.env.context.copy()
    if ctx.get('list_price_updated',False):
        return True
    ctx.update({'discount_updated':True})
    new_obj = self.with_context(ctx)
    PPC = (self.rapnet_price + (self.rapnet_price * self.discount / 100)
    list_price = PPC * new_obj.weight
    new_obj.price_caret = PPC
    new_obj.list_price = list_price

@api.onchange('list_price')
def list_price_change(self):
    ctx = self.env.context.copy()
    if ctx.get('discount_updated',False):
        return True
    ctx.update({'list_price_updated':True})
    new_obj = self.with_context(ctx)
    list_price = self.list_price / self.weight
    new_discount = (1 - (list_price / self.rapnet_price)) * -100
    new_obj.price_caret = list_price
    new_obj.discount = new_discount
```

**new_obj = self.with_context(ctx)**  using this line I am getting context value but didn't call other onchange while using self rather than new_obj other onchange calling but context will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use context for example to pass data/parameters from actions to python code. For instance into context you could set a specific view to use. I often use it to modify the view into field_view_get.

Have a look at this for more info

[What's the context?](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/how-to/concepts-16/whats-the-context-2236)

Comment: link is useful, but do you really think that context for exchanging information is trustable way ?

Comment: well, generally yes, but I know at least 1 case when it does not work: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677549/openerp-when-in-view-mode-fields-lose-context)

Answer (score 1):

The context is a python dictionary and is used to pass certain data to a method. Since nearly all methods have a context parameter you can use the context to pass data through several levels of python methods. For example you can set a context value in a XML-view and process it in the write() method of the osv object.

context.get('active_id',False)

returns the value of the key 'active_id'. If the key is not in the context, then it returns the value 'False'.

The value in 'active_id' is passed from the web client and contains the ID of the current selected record.

for more:- [Link](https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/how-to/concepts-16/whats-the-context-2236)